# Reproducing the "From Instancer" example from the Blender documentation

Tags: instances

[image]

Is anyone able to reproduce the *From Instancer* [example](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#id2) from the Blender documentation? Checking the option *From Instancer* in the *Texture Coordinate* node gives no effect in Blender 2.83.2 for me.

Here is my Blender file:
[image]

Comment: please show some screenshots or even share your file, it's hard to know where you could have missed something

Comment: @moonboots I attached my Blender file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1 - This is for *Cycles* only
- 2 - You need to be in *Rendered* mode (not *Material Preview*)